# To const or not to const?

Tags: c++, class, matrix, structure, constants

I'm writing a matrix class, which will have some methods which revolve around matrices like multiplication and inverses and the things of the sort. I understand it's C++ convention to make as much things as you can (especially member functions) constant, and I would like to know whether or not it's reasonable to make my rows an columns constant. This is my structure for the class:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
    namespace Math {
        class Matrix
        {
            private:
                //Variable initialization
                using data_type = double;
                const std::vector<std::vector<data_type>> m_rows;

                //I know this part isn't required but I'm doing it as a sort of code-shortener
                const int m_m, m_n;


            public:
                //Constructors
                Matrix(int rows, int cols) : m_m(rows), m_n(cols), m_rows(std::vector<std::vector<data_type>>(rows, std::vector<data_type>(cols, 0))) {};
                Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<data_type>> vect) : m_m(size(vect)), m_n(size(vect.at(0))), m_rows(std::move(vect)) {};


                //Non-static methods
                std::string asString() const;

                //Static methods
                static Matrix Identity(int dim); 
                static Matrix Multiply(Matrix& a, Matrix& b);
        };
}
```

Again, with the standards I'm trying to avoid making m_rows not constant, but I'm tempted to make it mutable with the sole reason being concerns of if the matrix needs to be changed using a for loop or something of the sort.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you are making a class to wrap the concept of a Matrix, do not do `std::vector<std::vector<data_type>>` , rather do `std::vector<data_type>` which contains `rows * cols` of elements, and calculate the `col + row * cols` index into the 1-D vector.  (Unless you want to have a sparse matrix, in which case you'll want a different approach.)

Comment: It's tempting to make as many member functions `const` as possible, since then the compiler will warn you when trying to modify an object that you shouldn't be.  As a practical matter you'll often find yourself trying to call a non-const function from a const function and find it doesn't work.

Comment: A `const` member variable implies that the data can *never* change after construction.  In other words, every operation must return a new matrix.  For some objects this behavior can be desirable, but allocating a whole new matrix for every step of a long calculation is bound to be quite slow.  I would prefer to leave `m_rows` mutable, but then mark individual functions as `const` as appropriate (e.g. `Multiply` should probably take two `const Matrix&`s.)

Comment: I guess that the matrix size shouldn't change once created. The exception is a null object, when you create a placeholder that later gets it's values from file or something. This however may beconsidered an antipattern because of mutability.

Comment: One more note: even more important is to make the parameters const references: `static Matrix Multiply(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);`

Answer (score 0):

As it happens I am also currently writing a Matrix class with its own iterators but from scratch. Anyway, ask yourself: Will the size of my matrix change at any point? Well, if you intend to assign to a matrix with another size, then the size will have to change. If you want to have a operator*=, that will change its size. But if you're ok with not having such functionality, const it! However, I won't in my project, for the reasons give.

Comment: Even smarter would be to make the size a part of the type: `template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>`. In this case you would prevent the operations with the arguments of wrong sizes.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov not really, then you would need to template everything dealing with your matrix class

Comment: Why not? Move your bugs from runtime to compiletime.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov There is a semantic difference though. You can't construct the matrix with runtime size values if it's a template.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov it wouldn't achieve that, it would only possibly create bugs, and again you couldn't have something like a vector of matrices

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Another down side is you cant easily put different sized matrices in a single container.

Comment: @NathanOliver, what is the reason of putting matrices of different sizes into a single container? How would you use that? You can at most print all of them, but there are no other applications. At least the application becomes very specific.

Comment: You could still, for example, find what matrix has the highest value inside of it, or do anything else with the matrices. Every application which has to work with matrices could benefit from having them in a container. Square each matrix, etc.

Comment: If the only operation you plan to do with those matrices is the max_element, you don't need matrices at all. That would be just some rectangular structures without any algebra on them. Be clear in your intentions and follow the Liskov principle. Otherwise beware of god objects, fat interfaces and other antipatterns.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov that was only one example and if having clean code is the objective, avoid templates, in that case, the performance boost would be almost nothing if not outright 0

Comment: Clean code implies SOLID, so Liskov principle is the requirement. Templates are not only the performance. Even more important is the fact that many types of errors are discovered in compile time. Matrix dimensions is one example.

Comment: Do you know what the Liskov substitution principle even is? Because you sure seem to reference it a lot. It doesn't apply here in any way. You repeat the same stuff again and again. Do not expect another reply to the same old stuff

Comment: @Mikdore, strictly speaking there could be no syntactic subtyping from C++ point of view if you put concrete Matrix objects of dynamic sizes into a single container. But this violates the notion of type: the attribute that defines operations on data (*an attribute of data which tells the compiler or interpreter how the programmer intends to use the data*). The size of the matrix becomes the part of it's type whenever you start adding them: `Matrix add(const Matrix &l, const Matrix &r);` Can you use this method with ANY pair of your matrices?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov think of how many times you had a vector of vectors, not a 2D vector, but a collection of them. Let's say you have n systems of linear equations, with x amount of coefficients, the logical thing to do would be to have a function that takes a vector of matrices, solves the equations, and returns a vector of matrices. Wikipedia says: "In mathematics, a matrix is a rectangular array" note that the dimensions do not define a matrix, as oposed to how the number of vertices define a Quadrilateral.

Comment: Returning back to Liskov: "a function that takes a vector of matrices, solves the equations". Each vector element is used not as a matrix per se, but as a linear equation input. A *linear equation* has no *add* / *multiply* operations, but it has an operation *solve* (while *matrix* cannot be "solved"). Moreover, the solution may be extended to any equation (quadratic, differential), or to any other task (logical puzzle), so the matrix becomes just a part of *some* types of tasks, and that implies composition. Anyway, the discussion has sense only if concrete code is considered.